# How to keep the following TSQL query from running my server at 100%?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, query-optimization

The following queries run in an sproc targeting the ItemData table in SQL Server 2008R2:

```
SELECT TOP(500) ItemListID, GeoCity, GeoState, GeoDisplay, Title, Link, Description, CleanDescription, OptimizedDescription, PubDateParsed, ImageBytes, DateAdded  FROM  (      SELECT TOP(500) ItemListID, GeoCity, GeoState, GeoDisplay, Title, Link, Description, CleanDescription, OptimizedDescription, PubDateParsed, ImageBytes, DateAdded, ROW_NUMBER()             
       OVER( ORDER BY ItemListID DESC )
       AS RowNumber  
       FROM ItemData  
       WHERE CONTAINS(Title, @FTSSearchTerm  ) -- ' + @OriginalSearchTerm + '"')   
       AND  ( WebsiteID=1 AND 
                                     (@GeoCity = '-1' OR GeoCity = @GeoCity)  AND
                                     (@GeoState = '-1' OR GeoState = @GeoState) )
                   ) ItemData   WHERE RowNumber >= ( @PageNum - 1) * @PageSize + 1   AND RowNumber <= @PageNum * @PageSize ORDER BY ItemListID DESC 

        SELECT @NumberOfResultsReturned = @@ROWCOUNT         

        SELECT @ActualNumberOfResults = COUNT(*) FROM ItemData WHERE CONTAINS(Title, @FTSSearchTerm  ) -- ' + @OriginalSearchTerm + '"')    AND  ( WebsiteID=1 AND       (@GeoCity = '-1' OR GeoCity = @GeoCity)  AND    (@GeoState = '-1' OR GeoState = @GeoState) )
```

Depending on the data the query uses either `CONTAINS` or `FREETEXT`.

With load this query runs very slow and peeks the server at 100%.

I have set the following indexes:

[image]

What do I need to do so these queries stop running so hot?

Thanks.

**-- UPDATE --**

The table has one clustered index which only consists of ItemListID, and FTS on Title and Description.

I have added a non-clustered index (incorrectly named in the Identity name) as follows:

[image: Non-clustered indexes]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without actually looking into the execution plan, it seems like you need a non-clustered index on Title, GeoCity, GeoState, and WebsiteID with the following include columns: ItemListID, GeoDisplay, Link, Description, CleanDescription, OptimizedDescription, PubDateParsed, ImageBytes, DateAdded

This will allow the execution plan to use the one non-clustered index that contains all of the information you are looking for in this query. Without it, it will use one of the indexes you showed and still have to go to the table to get the data you need.

This won't totally fix your problem though, depending on how much data is in your table, doing the Contains on Title to do searching will always be expensive. It would be best if you could leverage [full text searching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) to do the searching portion.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Ok, so I should remove the current indexes (except for the PK) then add one non-clustered index that inclused the fields you mentioned?  You mentioned that using CONTAINS is expensive (on Title), but I have already created a full text index on Title, and Description (the latter I am not currently using on my queries).  I noticed I have no schedules in its properties - do I need to add some auto-population scheduling?

Comment: I can't say you should remove any indexes without understanding how the rest of the system interacts with the database. You can however use some awesome queries from Glenn Berry to help you tune your indexes. https://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/tag/dmv-queries/

Comment: As for the full text search, awesome! Then there isn't anything more you should need to do in regard to that as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried to create a clustered index using with ItemDataID.  However, because I have Title and Description as part of my FTS, they are not available for inclusion in a clustered index.  That's fine.  However, I get a warning message indicating that the current index on the PK needs to remain as a single column, otherwise FTS will be disabled.  In short - can will creating a clustered index on the fields you mentioned, excluding the PK effectively do the same as what you recommended?

Comment: I recommended you create a non-clustered index. I would leave the clustered index generated from the PK alone at this time.

Comment: Thanks again, but it didn't seem to make a difference at all.  When I have several queries run at the same time, I'm experiencing the same slow-down.  If I remove the current clustered index (of the PK), can I create a new clustered index with the PK first, adding the other fields (in the order of usage of my queries), and still take advantage of FTS on Title and Description? (Updated above desc. with the latest)

Comment: Scratch that last question - as an index for FTS as the index must be a single-key-column, unique, non-nullable index.

Comment: When you added the non-clustered, the index columns should only need to be the ones used in a join or a where clause. All other columns should be added as include columns on that index. If you have too many index columns that are unrelated to the filtering, it will make your index less useful for that particular execution plan. Based on your screenshot, I think that's what's going on here.

Comment: Alright... so I did just that - only added the columns in the WHERE clause to the non-clustered index. I also created separate indexes on other fields that I use in other where.  In addition I added WITH(NOLOCk) to the query, but no change.  I wonder if there is an issue with having the FTS on two fields - Title and Description?